# Function works only with alert

Tags: click, load, alert, live

I have a form full generated with DOM. In that form, I have a button with the class "more-fields" and after clicking on this button I would like to show other hidden fields. But my script is not working without `alert()`. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(function() {
 $(".more-fields").on("click", function(){
  $(".other-fields").show();
 }); 
});
```

This is not working. But when i add alert() before click, than it is working:

```
$(function() {
 alert("xxx");
 $(".more-fields").on("click", function(){
  $(".other-fields").show();
 }); 
});
```

Why it is not working without alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
$(function() {
 $(document).on('click', '.more-fields', function() {
  $(".other-fields").show();
 }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

But I try to use that. 
It's no problem 
Maybe you should show your Html

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="Zh-TW">
    <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script> 
       $(function() {
     $(".more-fields").on("click", function(){
      $(".other-fields").show();
     }); 
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button class="more-fields">more-fields</button >
    <div class="other-fields" style="display: none;">
    <p>other-fields</p>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: My form is in DOM, yours in HTML. I cant post HTML or all JS code. It is a lot of pages of code.